# How can I call the input value on my function ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, fetch-api

I am trying to call the value of my input inside the form to my fetch function however it can't read it please help me. I was going to do a fetch post so I can insert it inside my table.

My function is like:

```
handleSubmit() {
  debugger
  function createNewProfile(profile) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Employee_Name', profile.Employee_Name);
    formData.append('Address', profile.Address);
    formData.append('Department', profile.Department);
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    }).then(response => response.json())
  }

  createNewProfile(profile)
      .then((json) => {
            // handle success
          }
      ).catch(error => error);
}
```

and this is my form where I want my

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div className="container">
        <div className="modal-body">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="Employee_Name"
                               className="EmployeeDetails"
                               value={this.props.Employee_Name}/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="Address"
                               className="EmployeeDetails"
                               value={this.props.Address}
                               onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Department</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"
                               name={this.props.Department}
                               className="EmployeeDetails"
                               value={this.props.Department}/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info" onClick={ this.handleSubmit} value=" Add Employee"/>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are controlling the form values from parent component, so i will suggest you to pass a submit function also from parent component and onClick of submit, do the api call in parent.

If you do api call in parent component, then you need to access the values by `this.state.key` and if you do the api call in child then you need to use `this.props.key` to access the values.

**Note:** I am assuming you are updating the input values in parent component on change in child component, because you passed the onChange function from parent.

**Api call in child component:**

```
handleSubmit(){
    let profile = this.props;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Employee_Name', profile.Employee_Name);
    formData.append('Address', profile.Address);
    formData.append('Department', profile.Department);
    fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        //handle success
    })
}
```

**Api call in parent component:**

```
handleSubmit(){
    let profile = this.state;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Employee_Name', profile.Employee_Name);
    formData.append('Address', profile.Address);
    formData.append('Department', profile.Department);
    fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        //handle success
    })
}
```

**Update:**

You need to bind the `handleSubmit` function in the constructor, write the constructor like this:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: im trying to add on my api

Comment: why is it saying null </3

Comment: did you bind the `handleSubmit` method in the constructor ? if not then write this line in the constructor: `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)`

Comment: where will i put it ? sorry im so new to this

Comment: hey what should i use a state or a props? im going to add data on my api?

Comment: if making the api call in child means in the same component you wrote the input elements then use props, if doing in parent from where you are passing the data then use state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144521/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-patricia-mari-maclang).